# swift mailer send email from yahoo to gmail error

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

```
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance();
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
    $message->setSubject("Meal Cancellation");
    $message->setBody($email_content, 'text/html');
    $message->setFrom(array("testing@yahoo.com" => "testing"));
    $message->setTo("testing@gmail.com");
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
    if($result){
        echo "1";
    }
```

Receive a yahoo email said:
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

testing@gmail.com
    host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.68.26]
    SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
    550-5.7.1 Unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's
    550-5.7.1 DMARC policy. Please contact administrator of yahoo.com domain if
    550-5.7.1 this was a legitimate mail. Please visit
    550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn about DMARC
    550 5.7.1 initiative. gn4si2239130pac.239 - gsmtp

May i know what's the problem and how to solve it

Comment: error tells you what you need to do

Comment: you're trying to pretend you're sending email from a yahoo account, but **NOT** going through yahoo's servers, therefore you're LYING about the source of the email, and it's properly being rejected. In other words, your email is basically being treated as spam and properly being treated as junk.

Comment: @MarcB is 100% right. If you're sending your internal staff an email notification then be sure to set the FROM address to an email tied to your domain or a "no-reply@" to ensure it goes through to you. Spoofing email (even if innocent in nature) is no good.